# How to get value of Eccentricity from struct of Eccentricity in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to print Eccentricity of each connected component of my image and following is part of my code:

```
[B,L] = bwboundaries(bw,'noholes');
stats = regionprops(L,'Eccentricity');

for k = 1:length(stats)
    stats(k);
end
```

But it doesn't really print any thing on output console. I want to get Eccentricity of each component on console.

And I want to store the float value of Eccentricity of each component in new one dimensional array so how do I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

The `;` in MATLAB suppresses the output of the executed line, and unlike most other languages is not required to terminate the end of a line. The easy way to "fix" this is to remove the `;` from the `for` loop:

```
for k = 1:length(stats)
    stats(k)
end
```

But it's a best practice to always have a `;` at the end of every line. Rather than display this way, consider using `disp()` instead:

```
for k = 1:length(stats)
    disp(stats(k));
end
```

Comment: It give output http://pastebin.com/4FVbsdBV but I want to store each float value in new one dimensional array ?

Comment: for k = 1: length(stats)
    output(k) = stats(k).Eccentricity;
end
solves my problem.